# Install php-fpm 5.6 on Ubuntu Xenial (16.04)

Tags: 16.04, php, php-fpm

I can see various solutions available for php5.6, but is it possible to get php-fpm 5.6 for Xenial?

Or do I have to manually download and build the package?

Comment: php-fpm is not contained within the ppa:ondrej/php repository

Comment: [PHP-FPM is now included in PHP core as of PHP 5.3.3.](https://php-fpm.org/download/)

Comment: After adding the repo `$ php-fpm` results in `bash: php-fpm: command not found`. So it seems the Ubuntu repo builds this as a separate package (same for PHP7).

Comment: I think it is `php5-fpm` and you install it?

Comment: Hmm might be on the right track here! I tried php5.6-fpm and it's downloading!

Comment: Though why wouldn't this package be shown in the `Overview of published packages` list though (https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Once you've added [the additional repository](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5.6-fpm
```

Comment: What is difference between  php5.6 and  php5.6-fpm?